# How to move an SCNNode to just below ARCamera?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm making an Augmented Reality app where the user has to throw a ball at a target. I used the following code to position the ball 10 cm in front of the screen:

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.z = -0.1
print(translation.debugDescription)
print(frame.camera.transform)
projectile.simdTransform = matrix_multiply(frame.camera.transform, translation)
```

Currently the game looks like this, but I want to move the ball to near the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution:

Replacing the following line:

```
translation.columns.3.z = -0.1
```

with:

```
translation.columns.3.x = -0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can use the following approach for **X**, **Y** and **Z** simultaneously:

```
translation.columns.3 = simd_float4(-0.1, 0, 0, 1)
```

The last element in the `columns.3` is the **homogeneous coordinate**, it equals `1`.

[image]

The columns of the matrix 4x4 are like these:

```
public var columns: (simd_float4, simd_float4, simd_float4, simd_float4)
```

Hope this helps.